# SaveAllInBackground doesn't work inside deleteAllInBackground as desired

Tags: android, parse-platform

SaveAllInBackground doesn't work inside deleteAllInBackground as desired.

I am trying to save a list of parseobjects using save all in background. To avoid duplicates in the table, I am querying for the already existing rows and deleting them if any and then save the new copy. Therefore I am calling the saveAllInBackground inside the deleteAllInBackground's callback.

The problem is this :

For ex: if the list to delete contains [a,b,c,d] and the list to upload has [a,b,c,d,e,f] only [e,f] get persised to parse. I am passing [a,b,c,d,e,f] to the saveAllInBackground but only [e,f] get persisted.

- Is there something I am missing? How to solve this?
- Can I use a different approach?
- Is there a better way to avoid duplicates? I dont want to add a
  beforeSave hook. The whole purpose of calling the saveAll is to reduce the number of API calls. I guess if I use beforeSave, I will have to run some queries in the cloud code anyway.

This is my code

```
            ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("PostChoice");

            query.fromPin();
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(final List<ParseObject> localList, ParseException e) {
                    if (localList != null && !localList.isEmpty()) {
                        List<ParseObject> postList = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
                        for (ParseObject object : localList) {

                            postList.add(object.getParseObject("post"));
                        }
                        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("PostChoice");
                        query.whereContainedIn("post", postList);
                        query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(List<ParseObject> parseCloudList, ParseException e) {

                                if (parseCloudList != null && !parseCloudList.isEmpty()) {
                                    ParseObject.deleteAllInBackground(parseCloudList, new DeleteCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void done(ParseException e) {
               // this gets executed and rows are accordingly deleted                             
                                            ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(localList, new SaveCallback() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void done(ParseException e) {
// this gets executed but the rows are not uploaded. 
//the locallist is not empty. it contains the right data.
                                                    editor.putLong(Four.LAST_CHOICE_SYNC_TIME, System.currentTimeMillis());
                                                    editor.commit();
                                                    Log.i("SyncChoiceService", "Synced Choices");
                                                }
                                            });
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                                else{
                                    ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(localList, new SaveCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                                            Log.i("SyncChoiceService", "Synced Choices");
                                            editor.putLong(Four.LAST_CHOICE_SYNC_TIME,System.currentTimeMillis());
                                            editor.commit();
                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }
                        });


                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have come up with a solution like this. and it meets my requirement. I use the updatedValue and delete the old ones and the remaining get updated as a whole list.

```
ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("PostChoice");

            query.fromPin();
            query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                @Override
                public void done(final List<ParseObject> localList, ParseException e) {
                    if (localList != null && !localList.isEmpty()) {

                        List<ParseObject> postList = new ArrayList<ParseObject>();
                        for (ParseObject object : localList) {

                            postList.add(object.getParseObject("post"));
                        }
                        ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("PostChoice");
                        query.whereContainedIn("post", postList);
                        query.whereLessThan("updatedAt",System.currentTimeMillis());
                        query.whereEqualTo("user", ParseUser.getCurrentUser());
                        query.findInBackground(new FindCallback<ParseObject>() {
                            @Override
                            public void done(final List<ParseObject> parseCloudList, ParseException e) {
                                if (parseCloudList != null && !parseCloudList.isEmpty()) {
                                    ParseObject.deleteAllInBackground(parseCloudList, new DeleteCallback() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void done(ParseException e) {
                                            Log.i("SyncChoiceService", "Deleted old  Choices");

                                        }
                                    });
                                }


                                    }
                                });


ParseObject.saveAllInBackground(localList, new SaveCallback() {
        @Override
        public void done(ParseException e) {
            Log.i("SyncChoiceService", "Synced Choices");
        }
    });

                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, if i understand you correctly you want to save only new data from localdb to parse backend.

Best and less request solution would be to have anther field in your table called "Draft" or "isUpdated" (name as you want). Role of this flag is to identify whether this field is saved in backend or not. if its a new field "isUpdated" is false else its true. Then in query you can query only the isUpdated is false. Then save them in backend. Then

1. You don't want to delete any data.
2. Reduce requests
3. Less unnecessary logic in your code.
4. it's clean

Hope this helps

Comment: Can we not do this without a flag? flags in the long run become a overhead. I prefer keeping the columns to the minimum and handle the logic in the code.

Comment: This is the method i would use, due to mentioned reasons. But the costs of my reputation points i would rather not help you.